# Why does displacement modifier produce a different (and unwanted) result when applied to a selected plane in a 3d object?

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I am trying to model 3d blocks of terrain by adding topography to the upper face of a block diagram.

[image: 3 steps to unwanted results]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the vertex group to achieve what you want. Take a look at the image.

[image]

Other option, could be to set the direction to apply the modifier, in this case to the Z axis, but it will replicate the effect on both faces (top and bottom) of the mesh.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason is a cube is connected to other vertices in 3D, unlike a 2D plane, and so calculates that way. So a plane would only stay within it's boundaries of y positioning (2D), whereas a 3D object is displaced in 3 dimensions.